# How can I get jenkins data to an HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jenkins

I have just followed the steps which were given in the Jenkins website. Now I can login into Jenkins using http://localhost:8080

When I use http://localhost:8080/api/json?pretty=true I can get JSON response from my localhost server. But when I try to get the data to a html page i.e., when I use url http://localhost:1234/foldername/file.html I'm unable to get the data using AJAX call. Below is the code I'm using for AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/json?pretty=true',
        dataType: 'json',
        //whatever you need
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('admin', 'admin'));
        },
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    function make_base_auth(user, password) {
        var tok = user + ':' + password;
        var hash = btoa(tok);
        return 'Basic ' + hash;
    }
```

I'm getting an authentication error.

Comment: Jenkins is pretty powerful.  Why are you trying to scrape it?

Comment: Ya the thing was I want to show graphical representation of total number of builds and other data in another dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients), Jenkins recommends using your user's API key provided via HTTP Basic Authentication, not its password.

Modern jQuery (1.5 or later) also has added a headers field to the options for [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:apitoken')}
```

However, what you describe here should do fine without these suggestions.

My assumption is that you are running into the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) since your client is based in a browser document, from a different origin (different port) than your Jenkins server runs on. You will need to add [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on your Jenkins server allowing your page's domain access to Jenkins resources, or have both Jekins API + your client page hosted from a single origin.

For your example here, you could use the [CORS Filter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin) and would need to add headers at least as permissive as follows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origins: http://localhost:1234
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

In production, you could either use a single origin, or update the list of origins to include wherever your dashboard lives in production, or if you're confident about Same-origin problems, * as a wildcard for any origin.

Comment: Where should I add those access controls?

Comment: Your Jenkins server has to do it, these are server response headers, not client request headers.